# Akka.Kafka - warning message - Resuming partitions

Tags: scala, akka, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, akka-stream

Am getting debug messages continuously as resuming the partitions for all the topics. Like below. This message prints every millisecond on my server continuously.

```
08:44:34.850 [default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Resuming partition test222-7
08:44:34.850 [default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Resuming partition test222-6
08:44:34.850 [default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Resuming partition test222-9
08:44:34.850 [default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Resuming partition test222-8
```

This 
Here is the code

```
val zookeeperHost = "localhost"
val zookeeperPort = "9092"
// Kafka queue settings
 val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
       .withBootstrapServers(zookeeperHost + ":" + zookeeperPort)
       .withGroupId((groupName))
       .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")

 // Streaming the Messages from Kafka queue
 Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topicName))
     .map(msg => {
       consumed(msg.record.value)
     })
     .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Please help to do the partition correctly to stop the DEBUG messages.

Comment: Did you continuously invoke KafkaConsumer.resume method?

Comment: I am not invoking the KafkaConsumer.resume method. I am invoking `Consumer.committableSource` one time from my Main class.

Comment: Do I need to do the partition configurations for Akka-Kafka? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the [reactive-kafka code](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/e7936ec06d8ad6ca4d2558e2bad0a66d375bac81/core/src/main/scala/akka/kafka/KafkaConsumerActor.scala) resumes every partition before starting to fetch:

```
consumer.assignment().asScala.foreach { tp =>
  if (partitionsToFetch.contains(tp)) consumer.resume(java.util.Collections.singleton(tp))
  else consumer.pause(java.util.Collections.singleton(tp))
}
def tryPoll{...}
checkNoResult(tryPoll(0))
```

KafkaConsumer.resume method is a no-op if the partitions were not previously paused.

Comment: I have not paused the partitions from my code. But Am getting the resuming partition continuously. Is there any ways to stop this? How do I handle this? Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @ArunKannan did you solve it ? I have the same problem